# Cannot find function "%dorng%" in R

Tags: r, foreach

I have a problem with R.
This function when is invoked gives me

`"could not find function "%dorng%"`

Am I missing some packages or what?

I have done `install.packages("doRNG")` which was successfully installed.
EDIT: the same with installing `rngtools` and `foreach`.

```
.algorithmA_1 <- function(binaryMatrix, alpha, beta, tries, p){
    allResults <- foreach(thisTry = 1:tries) %dorng% {
        res1 <- .BicBin(binaryMatrix, alpha, beta, p, proc_genes=TRUE) # Algorithm A_1 by columns
         res2 <- .BicBin(binaryMatrix, alpha, beta, p, proc_genes=FALSE) # Algorithm A_1 by rows
         if(res1$score > res2$score)
             return(res1)
         else
            return(res2)
    }
    maxCoords <- allResults[[which.max(sapply(allResults, function(x) x$score))]]
    return(list(rows=(maxCoords$x == 1), cols=(maxCoords$y == 1), score=maxCoords$score))
}
```

Comment: did you attach the package with `library(doRNG)` ?

Comment: First days with R...I will kill myself. Thank you very much, fantastic comment! :)

Comment: we've all been there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install package `doRNG` and attach the library:

```
install.packages("doRNG")
library(doRNG)
```